# Form ShowDialog function error and does not execute the statements below of it

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, dll, dll-injection

I have a DLL, when the dll is injected to a process it should show a windows form. The code below is executed when the dll is injected to a process. However, the ui->ShowDialog() code seems to fail and the statement below it does not execute. And also the error is not catched in the catch statement. The execution is just stopped on the ui->ShowDialog line. How can I make this work?

MainUI is extended from System::Windows::Forms::Form class.

```
try {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    MainUI^ ui = gcnew MainUI();
    ui->ShowDialog();
    printOutput("ui->ShowDialog() has been executed");
    Application::Run(ui);
}
catch (InvalidOperationException^ e) {
    printOutput("Exception catched");
}
```

Comment: @AlexF what should I do?

Comment: @AlexF I managed to show the form, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to add an if statement checking the Application::MessageLoop.

```
if (Application::MessageLoop == false) {
    printOutput("No message loop exists on this thread");
}

try {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application::Run(gcnew MainUI());
}
catch (InvalidOperationException^ e) {
    printOutput("Exception catched");
}
```